# Single and double quotes in Sql Server 2005 insert query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

There is single and double quotes in the address textbox .How can I insert into database. I am using SQL2005.
My code is as follows...

```
str = "exec sp_cust_reg '" + customer.Cust_Id + "','" + customer.Cust_Name + "','" + customer.Gender + "','" + customer.Acc_no + "','" + customer.Address + "','" + customer.Pin_no + "','" + customer.Phone_no + "','" + customer.Mobile_no + "','" + customer.Email + "','" + customer.Authorise + "'";
```

Address is jo"hn's house

Its Text Visualizer is as follows...

```
exec sp_cust_reg 'C7','George Joseph','Male','0001-212123','jo"hn's house','515151','04862787896','8888888888','johnyqw@gmail.com','N'
```

I used

```
string sql = str.Replace("\'", " ");.
```

Then I get

```
exec sp_cust_reg  C7 , George Joseph , Male , 0001-212123 , jo"hn s house , 515151 , 04862787896 , 8888888888 , johnyqw@gmail.com , N
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You escape `'` as `''`.

So instead of `str.Replace("\'", " ")` use `str.Replace("'", "''")`

Comment: @Petar..The string is exec sp_cust_reg 'C7','Johny Joseph','Male','0001-124578','john's house','666666','88888888888','5555555555','johnyqw@gmail.com','N'   After your code it becomes exec sp_cust_reg ''C7'',''Johny Joseph'',''Male'',''0001-124578'',''john''s house'',''666666'',''88888888888'',''5555555555'',''johnyqw@gmail.com'',''N''

Comment: no! you want to replace only the `'` that are in the values, i.e. customer.Cust_Name.Replace("'", "''"), etc.

Comment: This is a bad approach - parameterized SQL is a *far* better solution here.

Answer (score 8):

One word: **DON'T DO IT!**

Use **parametrized queries** instead - those are both safer (no SQL injection) and easier to work with, and perform better, too!

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_cust_reg", _connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// add parameters and their values
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customer.Cust_Id;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cust_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = customer.Cust_Name;
 ..... and so on - define all the parameters!

_connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
_connection.Close();
```

Comment: @marc_s....my insert query is in a remote webservice. I just pass the insert query as a string to Insert(string S) of my webservice.

Comment: @DavidJohn: awful design .... this is a **BIG WIDE OPEN BARN DOOR** for SQL injection. If I had to maintain this, I would toss that `Insert` method and create a new one with 1) name of the stored proc to call, and b) a list of `SqlParameter` to use in the call....

Comment: @marc_s...I am a beginner...Is it wrong to pass the insert query  as a string to a method in my webservice?

Comment: @DavidJohn: it's a **risk** that the query string can be manipulated, and that the remote webservice might just execute it without any validation/checks. Opens the door to attacks. **NOT** a recommended practice - it's better to have specific parametrized queries, and specify the parameters for the query separately (as `SqlParameter` instances) - it's better for performance and it's safer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Parameterized queries](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30147) 
 for giving the values, using the AddWithValue() of Parameters like

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_cust_reg",_connection);
cmd.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TheDate",customer.Cust_Id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cust_Name",customer.Cust_Name);

_connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
_connection.Close();
```

Why I am telling to use AddWithValue is - you explicitly set the sqldb.type and SQL knows exactly the dbtype when passed.